# integral and summation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $A_n =\{\omega\in\Omega: n \leq |X(\omega)|< n+1\} $. I need to show $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty}n p(A_n)$ $\leq$ $E|X| \leq \sum_ {n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)P(A_n)$

I try by begin with ${n \leq |X(\omega)|< n+1} $ with taking integral to all side

$$\int_\Omega n \,dP \leq \int_\Omega|X|\,dP\leq \int_\Omega( n+1 )dP$$

$$\int_{A_n} n  dP + \int_{A^c_n}n dP \leq\int_{A_n}(n+1)dP+\int_{A^c_n}(n+1)dP$$

what about this integral its equal zero  $\int_{A^c_n}(n+1)dP$ \,  $\int_{A^c_n}ndP$.

now how I can transform integration to summation ??

Comment: What are $A_{n}$ and x($\omega$) and $E|x|$?

Comment: $A_n$ is aset that defined above  and x is arandom variable and E|x| is the expectation of absolute value of x @MostafaAyaz

Comment: Do you mean $A_n = \{\omega : |X(\omega)| \in [n, n+1) \}$?

Comment: Now, it at least make sense to me

Comment: @dEmigOd yes that i mean

Comment: I made things more readable, do you agree with my edits?

Comment: thnx alot @Shashi i begin to learn latex

Comment: Hint: use the fact that $\Omega = \bigcup A_n$ and this union is disjoint.

Comment: more explian @Walton please

Comment: what about the first relation i use the greast integer number@Walton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that $\Omega = \bigcup A_n$ and $\{A_n\}$ are pairwise disjoint,
$$ \int_\Omega |X| dP = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{A_n} |X| dp \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) P(A_n)$$

Comment: exchanging limits and integrals need to be justified

Comment: this is easy answer ..... the idea is the union equal summation as disjoint thnx alot

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Regarding your approach - i don't agree with it. Specifically 3rd row is wrong. As $|X|$ could be much larger, than some specific $n$ on almost all $\Omega$

**Original:**

$|X|$ is a non-negative variable, so at least integrable.

Define a sequence of $Y_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n (n+1) \cdot 1_{[n, n+1)}$ - simple functions. All are non-negative, and the sequence is non-decreasing.

Let $0 \leq \varphi \leq |X|$ be some bounded function with finite support, then $\exists N, \forall n \geq N$ $\varphi \leq Y_n$.

Which leads us to state $\int \varphi~\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} \leq \int Y_n~\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n (n+1) \mathbb{P}(A_n)$

Since the above is right for all $n \geq N$, then
$\int \varphi~\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} \leq \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int Y_n~\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \mathbb{P}(A_n)$

As usual, such claim is right for any $\varphi$ which is $0 \leq \varphi \leq |X|$ bounded function with finite support, hence by definition
$\int |X|~\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P} = \sup\limits_{\text{such } \varphi}\int \varphi~\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}\leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} (n+1) \mathbb{P}(A_n)$

Comment: what about my attempt

Answer (score 0):

Let us start by defining $Y=|X|$. What you can do is to notice that $\lceil Y \rceil = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\mathbf{1}_{\{n+1> Y\geq n\}}$ (verify this!). Moreover we have $Y \leq \lceil Y \rceil$. Hence by monotonicity we have:
\begin{align}
E[Y]\leq E[\, \lceil Y \rceil\, ]
\end{align}
Moreover by [Fatou's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) we have:
\begin{align}
E[\, \lceil Y \rceil\, ] \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)P(n+1>Y\geq n)
\end{align} 
We are there since $P(n+1>Y\geq n)=P(A_n)$ we can conclude:
\begin{align}
E|X|\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)P(A_n)
\end{align}

Comment: In fact one has equality by using MCT, but Fatou is enough for this setting..