# Expectation and convergent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable, and let $A_n=\{\omega: n\leq|X(\omega)|< n+1 \}$.

How I can deduce

1. $E(X)$ is finite iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X|\geq n)$ is convergent,
2. If $E(X)$ is finite then $n P(|X| \geq n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Please hint for this question.

Comment: Why are the $A_n$ defined, they appear to be of no use.

Comment: *Hint.* We have $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(|X| \geq n) \leq E |X| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(|X| \geq n) $$ and $$ n P(|X| \geq n) = E( n \mathbf{1}_{\{|X| \geq n\}} ), \qquad n \mathbf{1}_{\{|X| \geq n\}} \leq |X| $$.

Comment: please explian part 2 for me @SangchulLee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** 1. Use the expression $E(|X|)= \int_{0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq t) \text{d} t$ which can be derived by Fubini's Theorem, and the fact that $ \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq n+1) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq t)\leq \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq n) $ when $ n+1\geq t \geq n $.

2. Notice that $|X| 1_{|X|\geq n} \geq n 1_{|X|\geq n}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591626/integral-and-summation this question follow this too  .. I use this relation to prove the first side in 1) $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty}n p(A_n)$ $\leq$ $E|X|  what about the other side in 1@calrk

Comment: what about 2. if i take n goes $\infty$